# vb.net calculations for multiple condition

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I need to calculate and get a total amount for a unit with multiple calculation conditions. If I enter an amount in a textbox and press enter the second textbox should display a total amount for the below conditions.
        (if unit = 450)
0-100 = 3.00 // 101-200 = 5.00 // 201-300 = 7.00 // over 300 = 10.00
if i press enter after entering the unit as 450 second textbox should display total as 2000.00. I am new to vb.net can anyone help me to do this
(for first 100 => 300.00 / second 100 => 500.00 / third 100 => 700.00 / fourth 100 => 500.00 altogether totally 2000.00)

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far, I know you're new but you must have tried something. Let us see your code

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple console application to illustrate the process. The idea is to go from the highest range to the lowest and always check if we have to take items from the current range.

```
Class AmountLimit
    Public Property AmountLowerBound As Integer
    Public Property Value As Double

    Public Sub New(amountLowerBound As Integer, value As Double)
        Me.AmountLowerBound = amountLowerBound
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub
End Class

Sub Main()
    'Specify the values for each range. The first number is the lower bound for the range
    Dim amountLimits As New List(Of AmountLimit)
    amountLimits.Add(New AmountLimit(0, 3))
    amountLimits.Add(New AmountLimit(100, 5))
    amountLimits.Add(New AmountLimit(200, 7))
    amountLimits.Add(New AmountLimit(300, 10))

    Console.Write("Enter the total amount: ")
    Dim totalAmount = Integer.Parse(Console.ReadLine())

    Dim finalValue As Double = 0
    For i As Integer = amountLimits.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        'Check if our total amount is greater than the current lower bound
        Dim currentRange = amountLimits(i)
        If (totalAmount > currentRange.AmountLowerBound) Then
            finalValue += (totalAmount - currentRange.AmountLowerBound) * currentRange.Value
            totalAmount = currentRange.AmountLowerBound
        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(finalValue)
End Sub
```